# Flex Mobile Back Button

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I search all through the internet and all topics about taking control of the back button in views are saying same thing:

```
override protected function backKeyHandler():void
{
    //Block native 'back' behavior.
}
```

But when I write this code into my views I always taking same error:

1020: Method marked override must override another method.

I look for this but didn't find a solution.

Comment: but where did you write this method, in which class?

Comment: I just realize that it can be only on Main mxml file. I was trying to use it on my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method isn't defined in some parent; then it can't be overriden.  Just remove the 'override' keyword from your method:

```
protected function backKeyHandler():void
{
    //Block native 'back' behavior.
}
```

This method will do nothing unless you add an event listener for it to be called.  If you're using an MXML [View](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html), you can add your listener to the [backKeyPressed](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event%3abackKeyPressed) event:

```
<s:View backKeyPressed="backKeyHandler()">

</s:View>
```

I'll add that this is for mobile applications only.

I can't comment on specific code you found on the Internet without actually knowing what that code or documentation was.

Answer (score 0):

A good article about Back button issue: http://theorynine.com/labs/taking-control-of-the-back-button-in-views-adobe-air-flex-mobile/